# Flutter json parsing failed without any error

Tags: flutter

I am trying to parse json response, but it is returning null. Here is the remote sample json response:

```
count   20
next    null
previous    null
results 
0   
id  1
name    "some name"
name_bn "another name"
price   88
price_bn    "৮৮"
old_price   false
old_price_val   null
old_price_val_bn    null
image   
0   
image_mobile_feature_list   "https://ex.com/m…fe708439802736d8ea7.webp"
image_mobile_product_details    "https://ex.com/m…e542aaf37cb52c44523.webp"
slug    "example"
short_description_opt   false
short_description   "<ul class=\"\" style=\"m…avoid;\"><br></li></ul>"
short_description_bn    ""
description_opt true
description "<ul class=\"\" style=\"m…avoid;\"><br></li></ul>"
description_bn  "<ul class=\"\" style=\"m…avoid;\"><br></li></ul>"
max_item    1
size    false
size_list   []
color   false
color_list  []
unit    false
unit_en null
unit_bn null
ranking 3

//next object
```

product model:

```
class ProductModel {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String nameBn;
  final String price;
  final String priceBn;
  final bool oldPrice;
  final String oldPriceVal;
  final String oldPriceValBn;
  final List<ImageBunny> image;
  final String slug;
  final String shortDescriptionOpt;
  final String shortDescription;
  final String shortDescriptionBn;
  final int maxItem;
  final bool size;
  final List<String> sizeList;
  final bool color;
  final List<String> colorList;
  final bool unit;
  final String unitBn;
  final String unitEn;
  final int ranking;

  ProductModel(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.nameBn,
      this.price,
      this.priceBn,
      this.oldPrice,
      this.oldPriceVal,
      this.oldPriceValBn,
      this.image,
      this.slug,
      this.shortDescriptionOpt,
      this.shortDescription,
      this.shortDescriptionBn,
      this.maxItem,
      this.color,
      this.colorList,
      this.ranking,
      this.size,
      this.sizeList,
      this.unit,
      this.unitBn,
      this.unitEn
      });


  }
```

image model:

```
class ImageBunny {
  final String imageMobileFeatureList;
  final String imageMobileProductDetails;
  ImageBunny({
    this.imageMobileFeatureList,
    this.imageMobileProductDetails,
  });
}
```

and the method for response parsing:

```
Future<List<ProductModel>> _parseProductsFromResponse() async {
    List<ProductModel> productsList = <ProductModel>[];

    var response = await http.get('https://url');


    var dataFromResponse = json.decode(response.body);

    dataFromResponse['results'].forEach(
      (newProduct) {
        print(newProduct);  // printing only 1st object
        //parse the product's images
        List<ImageBunny> imagesOfProductList = [];

        newProduct["image"].forEach(
          (newImage) {
            imagesOfProductList.add(
              ImageBunny(
                imageMobileFeatureList: newImage["imageMobileFeatureList"],
                imageMobileProductDetails: newImage["imageMobileProductDetails"],
              ),
            );
          },
        );

        // parse Size List
        List<String> sizeList = [];
        newProduct["size_list"].forEach((value) {
          sizeList.add(value);
        });


        // parse Color List
        List<String> colorList = [];
        newProduct["color_list"].forEach((value) {
          var color = value.toString();
          var colorVal = color.substring(1, color.length);
          colorList.add(colorVal);
        });


        //parse new product's details
        ProductModel product = ProductModel(
          id: newProduct["id"],
          name: newProduct["name"].toString(),
          nameBn: newProduct["name_bn"].toString(),
          price: newProduct["price"].toString(),
          priceBn: newProduct["price_bn"].toString(),
          oldPrice: newProduct["old_price"],
          oldPriceVal: newProduct["old_price_val"] != null? newProduct["old_price_val"].toString(): "",
          oldPriceValBn: newProduct["old_price_val_bn"] != null? newProduct["old_price_val_bn"].toString(): "",
          slug: newProduct["slug"].toString(),
          shortDescriptionOpt: newProduct["short_description_opt"],
          shortDescription: newProduct["short_description"].toString(),
          shortDescriptionBn: newProduct["short_description_bn"].toString(),
          maxItem: newProduct["max_item"],
          size: newProduct["size"],
          sizeList: sizeList,
          color: newProduct["color"],
          colorList: colorList,
          unit: newProduct["unit"],
          unitBn: newProduct["unit_bn"] != null? newProduct["unit_bn"].toString() : "",
          unitEn: newProduct["unit_en"] != null? newProduct["unit_en"].toString() : "",
          ranking: newProduct["ranking"],
          image: imagesOfProductList,
        );

        print(product);  // not printing anything
        print("hit");  // not printing anything

        productsList.add(product);
      },
    );

    return productsList;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the http response that you've provided, it's unclear if the response has a List in each objects. If the http response that you've provided is the actual object in a List, the likely culprit in this issue is that the parsed response isn't being added to the List.

```dart
var dataFromResponse = json.decode(response.body);

List<ProductModel> productsList = [];
List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(dataFromResponse).map((Map model) {
  // Add ProductModel mapped from json to List<ProductModel>
  productsList.add(ProductModel.fromJson(model as Map<String, dynamic>));
}).toList();
```

If you need help to generate a model for the http json response, you can use packages like [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable).